# Javascript elements being placed in different locations in FF and Chrome, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a browser based game with pure JS, and am getting different results in FF and Chrome on where my elements are being positioned.  Too be specific, my elements with the css class "cup" are rendering in very different locations, which is game breaking.  Firefox is placing these elements where I would like them to be, chrome is not.  I have a live example here:  http://beerwar.com/game/index.html

If a picture of the difference I am seeing would be helpful, I will upload one.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="game.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
#table {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#ball {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px black solid;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

.cup {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**game.js**

```
var players = [];

window.onload = function () {

    var player = {id:1, goals:0, shots:0}
    players[0] = player;

    player = {id:2, goals:0, shots:0}
    players[1] = player;

    var table = document.createElement("img");
    table.src = "images/table.png";
    table.id = "table";

    document.body.appendChild(table);

    var ball = document.createElement("div");
    ball.id = "ball";
    document.body.appendChild(ball);
    ball.style.top = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + (table.offsetHeight / 2) - (ball.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
    ball.style.left = table.getBoundingClientRect().left + (table.offsetWidth / 2) - (ball.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";

    //Player 1 cups.
    var cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.top = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) - cup.offsetWidth + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.top = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.top = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + cup.offsetWidth + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.top = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + cup.offsetHeight + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.top = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + cup.offsetHeight + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.top = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + (cup.offsetHeight * 2) + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";

    //Player 2 cups.
    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.bottom = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) - cup.offsetWidth + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.bottom = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.bottom = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + cup.offsetWidth + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.bottom = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + cup.offsetHeight + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.bottom = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + cup.offsetHeight + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";

    cup = document.createElement("img");
    cup.src = "images/cup.png";
    cup.className = "cup";
    document.body.appendChild(cup);
    cup.style.bottom = table.getBoundingClientRect().top + (cup.offsetHeight * 2) + "px";
    cup.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (cup.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that FF is the correct one?

Comment: Yes Zze, I'll add that to my question thanks.  FF is rendering correctly, but I myself am a Chrome user, so that's unacceptable, I know lots of people use Chrome now.

Comment: Side comment, don't repeat yourself! Each cup creation varies very little. Move that into a function that takes placement parameters.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I thought about doing it in a for loop.  I was planning on refactoring once I had a working prototype, which is still a ways to go.  But I will take that advice, then I can call it when I resize my window.  Currently resizing breaks the intended placement until I add a handler for onresize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like a race condition; your code that accesses `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` assumes that the elements using the image source have resized already.

I would preload the images and get their sizes beforehand, or just have a variable containing those sizes, then use those static sizes to do the positioning logic rather than assuming that the cup elements have already computed their sizes.

**Update**:

Preloading is probably overkill; just store the width + height in variables. If you do want to preload (so the code doesn't change if the image changes), you can use this technique:

```
function getImageSize(src, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    callback({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
  }
  img.src = src;
}
```

Then consume it like this:

```
getImageSize('/path/to/img.png', function(size) {
    var width = size.width;
    var height = size.height;

    // do stuff with width & height
});
```

Comment: Hey Jacob, so you think this will solve this specific problem?  And by pre-load, do you mean inserting the img elements into index.html instead of creating and appending them to the document body with JS?  Thanks for the response by the way.

Comment: You don't even have to insert the images; added sample code.

Comment: Very helpful stuff, I really appreciate it.  It seems that the img.onload event is going to be really important for making browser games with JS.